# Integral $\int \frac{x}{\left(1-x^3\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$

Tags: integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

I thought this integral was simple, but it turns out it's not.

$$I=\int \frac{x}{\left(1-x^3\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$$

I tried the substitution $1-x^3=\frac{1}{t}$, but that leaves me again with $x = \sqrt{1-t^2}$, which doesn't simplify things. Then I tried $x = \sin(t)$, which gets me to:
$$\int \frac{\sin t}{\left(1-\sin t\right)\left(1+\sin t+\sin^2 t\right)}dt$$

This looked solvable so I did another substitution: $\tan(\frac{t}{2})=u$, after a few steps I got this:

$$\int \:\frac{\left(u+u^3\right)du}{\left(u^2-2u+1\right)\left(2u^3+3u^2+4u+1\right)}$$

which is still too complicated. What am I missing? Any ideas?

**Update**: After splitting this function into

$$I=\frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx + \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{x-1}{\left(1+x+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx$$

It gets a bit easier. I think I can solve the first integral. But, how do I solve the second?

Thank you!

Comment: After a quick check on Wolfram, this is doable, but a little nightmare. I mean an awful nightmare.

Comment: please see what WA gives https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+x%2F((1-x%5E3)((1-x%5E2)%5E0.5))

Comment: Use partial fraction decomposition,

$$\dfrac y{1-y^3}=\dfrac A{1-y}+\dfrac{By+C}{1+y+y^2}$$

$$\implies y=A(1+y+y^2)+(1-y)(By+C)$$

Or $y^3-1=(y-1)(y-\omega)(y-\omega^2)$


$y=1\implies3A=1$

Constant $\implies0=A+C\iff C=-A $

Coefficients of $x^2\implies 0=A-B\iff A=B$

Comment: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754586

Comment: How is this duplicate question asked 30 minutes after the above linked one?

Answer (score 3):

After splitting the integral as follows
\begin{align}
&\int \frac{x}{\left(1-x^3\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx
\\
=& \ \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx + \frac{1}{3}\int \frac{x-1}{\left(1+x+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx
\end{align}
apply the Euler substitution ${\sqrt{1-x^2}}=({1+x})t$ to evaluate the two integrals

\begin{align}
&\int \frac{1}{\left(1-x\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx 
=-\int \frac1{t^2}dt=\frac1t\\ \\
&\int \frac{x-1}{\left(1+x+x^2\right)\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\\
=&\int\frac{4t^2}{t^4+3}dt
= 2\int\frac{t^2+\sqrt3}{t^4+3}+ \frac{t^2-\sqrt3}{t^4+3} \ dt\\
= &\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\sqrt3}}\tan^{-1}\frac{t^2-\sqrt3}{t\sqrt{2\sqrt3}}
 - \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\sqrt3}}\coth^{-1}\frac{t^2+\sqrt3}{t\sqrt{2\sqrt3}}
\end{align}